# How to debug unaligned accesses on amd64 using Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit, alignment

I would like to debug and profile some 64-bit software performing unaligned accesses, like in the following example:

```
int foo[2] = { 1, 2 };
*((int *)((char *)foo + 2)) = 3;
```

### The gcc way

I know of two ways to do so when using **gcc** and **gdb**. The first one is by enabling the *aligned check* bit (bit 18) in the `eflags` register, directly in my C or C++ code:

```
asm volatile("pushf \n"
             "pop %%rax \n"
             "or $0x40000, %%rax \n"
             "push %%rax \n"
             "popf \n" ::: "rax");
```

This is very handy because I can choose within the application itself whether to bypass unaligned access checks or not, for instance when calling known faulty libraries.

The other way is from **gdb**, at any moment while debugging the executable:

```
set $eflags |= 1<<18
```

Again, this can be enabled or disabled at will, scripted etc. Very handy.

### Visual Studio

Now I have been totally unable to do the same using **Visual Studio 2008** or **2010** on Vista64. Inline assembly in a C++ program is [no longer available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in x64 mode in any version of Visual Studio, but I can use [intrinsics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/10/18/new-intrinsic-support-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) instead:

```
#include <intrin.h>
/* ... */
__writeeflags(__readeflags() | 0x40000);
```

This is exactly the same code as on Linux. It *sort of works*: I get the exception when my faulty code is run. Except the `EFL.AC` flag is reset to zero each time a breakpoint is hit. Which means I cannot properly debug a large application with lots of complicated breakpoints unless I litter the code with calls to my asm function.

So I tried to manually change `EFL |= 0x40000` from the Visual Studio register debug session (which is exactly what I usually do on Linux). No effect either, the bit is set to zero as soon as I resume the debugging. Which means I cannot properly debug code for which I do not have the source code.

I don't understand what's going on here. Is it Visual Studio forcibly setting `EFL.AC=0`? If so, can I disable that "feature"? Also, is there a way to enable/disable `EFL.AC` during a debug session?

How do real world Windows developers track unaligned accesses in their code?

**Edit**: found out about [`__readeflags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983406%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which was not in the [list of x64 intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azcs88h2.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, all the register values should be saved and restored.  Consider filing a bug report: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/13/451329.aspx - looks like the link is broken, it's now: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Comment: "How do real world Windows developers track unaligned accesses in their code?". Being a primarily Windows developer myself, I think they just never do it, unless the code has to run on Itanium. And if it has to run on Itanium, the exception will tell the places. What is the real overhead of unaligned access on x86? BTW, you can still use assembly on x64, in .asm files, just not inline assembly.

Comment: @Tim: thanks for the hint, I will file a report. @Vladislav: I plan to write an article with comprehensive benchmarks about the issue; in serious corner cases I have seen 400% performance improvement when realigning data, but it's usually below 10%. Often worth investigating, though.

Comment: Bug report [submitted here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657947). For now they do not seem to be able to reproduce the issue, but I think I provided enough additional information for them to reproduce it.

Comment: Usually, the cost of an unaligned access is just that if it spans a cache line boundary, two cache lines have to be fetched from memory instead of one. On x86, the cost is generally negligible. On other platforms, it may be much more significant (or it might just result in an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately when debugging the x64 debugger in VS clears the alignment check flag on *any* exception (including the one thrown to step into the debugger in the first place).  Have you tried stepping through the code using windbg (a much more powerful windows debugger)?  I haven't been able to try it with the AC flag but it should be simple with r efl= or directly from the registers window.
If you don't have windbg installed, you can get it from the newest Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that VS can't actually do the job, and for suggesting windbg. I have debugged the application on Linux instead, but I will definitely try windbg next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use asmjit http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/

Comment: I don't follow - how would that help detect unaligned accesses? It looks like it might be a way to compile the flags change but Sam already has a solution for that in both MSVC and GCC.

Comment: Not really related to what I was looking for, but thanks anyway for letting me know about this interesting project!

Answer (score 0):

A very messy workaround is to have a thread in your program that constantly sets this bit. Every 100 ms or so.

Then you will know that shortly after you resume from your breakpoint, the alignment will be checked again. Not 100% safe but it might be good enough.

Comment: @Sam: You could do some crazy hack with `SuspendThread`, `GetThreadContext`, and `SetThreadContext` to set the EFLAGS of another thread.  But please don't ever ship production code that does that.